# fade in a page works well and slidedown doesn't work

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I have 2 pages when button in page1 is clicked it will linked to the page 2, then the page2 will load with transition. The page loads with fade in and doesnt work with slidedown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").css("display", "none");
            $("body").fadeIn(2000);

    });
```

The code above works well,but the below doesnt work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").css("display", "none");
            $("body").slideDown(2000);

    });
```

My full code

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=1.0)">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>About</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/jovine/Desktop/Anything/BAS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/jovine/Desktop/Anything/BAS/jquery.fullbg.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="basabout.css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){ 
            $("body").slideUp(1).delay(2000).slideDown('slow');


});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<img class="fullbg" src="background2.png" id="background" style="z-index:-9999; " />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#background").fullBg();
});
</script>

<div id="header" class="header">
<img class="title" src="aboutus.png">
<br>
<img class="triangle" src="triangle.png">
</div>
<div id="content" class="content">
    <img class="subtitle" src="about.png">
    <br />
    <p class="subtitle_content">We are the voice of the Beauty industry in Singapore.
    <hr class="divider">
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="peoples.png" style="margin-left:70px;">
        <img src="roll.png" style="margin-left:340px;">
        <img src="mic.png" style="margin-left:440px;">
        </div>
        <div class="logo_title">
        <img src="whoarewe.png" style="margin-left:40px;">
        <img src="whatwedo.png" style="margin-left:320px;">
        <img src="whatscomingup.png" style="margin-left:420px;">
        </div>
        <div id="logo_content" class="logo_content">
        <p class="content1">BAS stand for Beauty Association of<br>Singapore. BAS was built to contribute<br>to the development, advancement and<br>prestige of the Beauty industry in<br>Singapore.</p>
        <p class="content2">We are inspired by purpose, and we<br>strive to be the voice of the burgeoning<br>Beauty industry in Singapore.</p>
        <p class="content3">STAY TUNED!</p>
        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are slideDown and also doing display : none so how can you able to see the effect ? Refer this link : http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code, please?

Comment: Thanks for comment. im very new to jquery and never touch with it before. After I had read the link you share, I still dont understand that why the fade in is worked but slidedown is no response eventhough the fade in is with display:none

Comment: Yeah its working in jsfiddle see http://jsfiddle.net/yP3a4/1/ but not when in tried in my own html page

Comment: ya this is exactly wht i want but it didnt works in my html page too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yP3a4/2/ this works fine too in jsfiddle but doesnt in my html page

Comment: @jovine : Check my new answer this code is working for me in html page also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save jQuery from [jQuery download](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js) Link and save it in a folder name xyz. In same folder copy the following code with the .html. Now run the HTML page. works fine for me.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
    <div>hello how are you</div>
    <p>See it is working</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").slideDown(1).delay(2000).slideUp("slow");

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo:** [slideDown in jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/SphPy/2/)

You can try this so that you can see the effect of slideDown :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").slideUp(1).delay(2000).slideDown('slow');
});
```

**For detail** you can refer the **jQuery Documentation Page** :[jQuery slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

**OR**

You can try

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

as few elements not be completely loaded at the time of `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: I had used this

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").slideUp(1).delay(2000).slideDown('slow');
    });

It seems work cause it is blinking the page but it doesnt slide my page..
Any info I can provide to make it works?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your full code...?? or can you create a jsfiddle for your code...??

Comment: As per my understanding some of the code of your body part may be having some blinking effect. please post whole code or at least the body part of your code..??

Comment: I have edited my question and added my full code.. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot and appreciated!